# Time.Sleep between arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF in Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages

I'm building a code in Python to export in geotiff my imagery.

I need specific spots so I created a Data Driven Pages with polygons.

Everything works fine, except that my imagery layer takes a long time to be completely draw, and the output of my script shows just small parts of what I want. Please, see image below:

[image: Time to load]

So, what I need is a way to insert time.sleep in my python script to wait until imagery layer is completely loaded.

This is my script:

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
ar = df.extent.height / df.extent.width
for page_number in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = page_number
    print "Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Users\Istus\Documents\XXXXXXXX\Imagery\mapas\GEOTIFF\map_" + str(page_number) + ".tiff", df, 9306,9306*ar, resolution=300, geoTIFF_tags=True)
del mxd
```

I'm using ArcMap 10.1 and Python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have a solution for you.  I have been testing with this a large data set I have, and this may be provide the results you're looking for.

Adding to your code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
ar = df.extent.height / df.extent.width
for page_number in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = page_number
    #here I am taking the active data frame's extent and passing it back to the frame
    #ArcMap seems to hang at the point until it is rendered
    extent = df.extent
    df.extent = extent
    print "Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Users\Istus\Documents\XXXXXXXX\Imagery\mapas\GEOTIFF\map_" + str(page_number) + ".tiff", df, 9306,9306*ar, resolution=300, geoTIFF_tags=True)
del mxd
```

I set up DD pages on my large data set and just added a print message after my extent change.  I am watching it and it is rendering my layers (like 50+/-) before it prints my message and moves on.  It is a bit hacky, but I didn't see any properties that tell if the data frame is drawing or not.

I don't have a big enough image to test it in the same way you're doing things so it looks like vector layers are drawing.  If I can find a way to monitor drawing in arcpy, I will edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issues. I found that if I didn't use my computer while the processing was being implemented, I wouldn't lose any data in the images.